# No web-console in rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-console

I just installed web console with rails 4.2 :

```
gem 'web-console', :group => :development

bundle install
```

And when i restart the server

```
passenger start
```

When I load an error page, there is no console. Why?

Comment: Just to check - are you sure that you are working in the valid environment?

Answer (score -1):

If you want show web console in your Desired Page.

Add this line in page any where

```
<%= console %>
```

Then it will render web console.

Comment: To be sure i tried, it does not work. On top of that the console should appear on error pages.